# IntelliJ IDEA File FileNotFoundException, directory and file exists?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So this same project runs fine in Eclipse. I'm trying to run it using IntelliJ IDEA, and getting this error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: config\server.ini (The system cannot find the path specified)

The config directory and the server.ini file are both definantly there. Is there something Im missing? I know IntelliJ comes with the Ant build system, do I need to write some kind of build file to include the /config directory when building?

If not, what might be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure your file actually exists, this is most probably caused by the relative path given (`config/server.ini` instead of e.g. `/home/foobar/config/server.ini`). I assume IntelliJ IDEA is running your project under a different working directory than Eclipse. Check that in your run configurations.

Comment: Ah brilliant thanks. In my run configuration, the "Working directory" was the folder that was one directory up and contained my project module. Changing it to be my project module fixed it right up.